# ADC0808 IC working correctly occasionally

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, adc, circuit-design

I am using [ADC0808CCN](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc0808-n.pdf) for a project on converting analog signal to digital signal. It has an inbuilt multiplexer using which we have to provide an analog signal to one of the pin. However what happens is ;

1. Sometimes it latches to a particular value say 1000000 and remains at there no matter how many times Start of Conversion is pressed which should set the inner counter to 0.
2. Sometimes it gives slightly wrong output off by 100 or 1000 and when I press Start of conversion, it gives correct output, so its not reliable every time.
3. And most seriously , Suppose the control for multiplexer according to Datasheet are such that input pin 1 should be active, instead, it works only when the input is given to pin 5 for one particular IC and pin 3 for other.

   I have been trying to fit it in logic since 3 days however each day some new error happens. I have replaced it twice from my college lab and now the technician doesn't want to replace it anymore . What is amiss here ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a schematic?

Comment: It's just that your design does not meet the timing specifications.  Which ones have you not verified?

Comment: Added schematic

Comment: What is the voltage on the START pin when you have it connected to 5V? Why is there an LED connected to that pin with no current limiting resistor? Are you debouncing the switch? Please write more clearly...your 5 looks like a sloppy 3.

Comment: I have used resistors with led but omitted them to avoid clumsiness in diagram.

Comment: As i have shown in figure, the frequency of 555 timer is 33 Hz so i thought it is too low for a phenomenon like switch bouncing to affect my circuit because bouncing should be occurring at ns scale.

Comment: Improved diagram

Comment: But how does one explain in5 is selected for address 000 ?

Answer (score 1):

Posted as an answer as there is too much for a comment.

There are a number of issues here:

**1** The conversion start button has not been [debounced](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/debouncing-buttons), so there will (not may) be multiple (dozens) of start conversion pulses for each button press.

**2** There does not appear to be any [decoupling](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/what-is-a-decoupling-capacitor-and-how-do-i-know-if-i-need-one/2274) at all.

**3** The LEDs need [current limiting resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138368/calculating-resistors-value-to-use-it-with-a-led).

Devices like this need a fair amount of support circuitry to operate properly. Given the schematic you have posted, I am actually quite surprised you get *any* valid results.

Getting different results from different ICs is hardly a surprise here, incidentally; subtle differences device to device in a situation like this almost guarantees that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcd9Hd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Typical debounce circuit. Use a [schmitt trigger buffer](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G17).

Comment: As i have shown in figure, the frequency of 555 timer is 33 Hz so i thought it is too low for a phenomenon like switch bouncing to affect my circuit because bouncing should be occurring at ns scale

Comment: I have used resistors with led but omitted them to avoid clumsiness

Comment: You must show what you actually built.  If you omit LED resistors from the drawing "to avoid clumsiness", we can only assume that you omitted them from your circuit as well.

Comment: Added resistors

Comment: But how does one explain In5 is selected for address input as 000

Answer (score 0):

The clock frequency should be 640kHz , it is mentioned specifically in datasheet. By the way,  ADC0804 has an in-built clock , you need to connect pin 3 and pin 19 by a 10k ohm resistor and put a 150pF capacitor between pin 3 and ground.